# Game of Life as a React app

Tags: performance, html, react.js, game-of-life, jsx

I think the general functionality is there, but sometimes it looks a little slow/clunky when I try to run my app. Highlighting cells can be slow as it skips over some of the cells I hover over if my mouse is moving somewhat fast. Also the speed the grid evolves doesn't always consistent.

I suspect that calling setState() so often is a bit heavy? I was also wondering if there are "better" ways to do the styling of the grid.

https://jsfiddle.net/bonbonlemon/49jzdo1n/

JSX:

```
class GameOfLife extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const grid = this.createNewGrid();

    this.state = {
        grid: grid,
      isPointerDown: false,
      pointerStatus: false,
      isStarted: false,
      intervalId: 0,
      ticksPerSecond: 10
    };

    this.updateCell = this.updateCell.bind(this);
    this.handlePointerDown = this.handlePointerDown.bind(this);
    this.handlePointerOver = this.handlePointerOver.bind(this);
    this.handlePointerUp = this.handlePointerUp.bind(this);
    this.evolve = this.evolve.bind(this);
    this.clearGrid = this.clearGrid.bind(this);
    this.updateTicksPerSecond = this.updateTicksPerSecond.bind(this);
    this.toggleStart = this.toggleStart.bind(this);
  }

  createNewGrid() {
    let grid = [];
        for (let row = 0; row < 40; row++) {
        grid.push([]);
        for (let col = 0; col < 40; col++) {
        grid[row].push(false);
      }
    }

    return grid;
  }

  updateCell(e, updatePointerDown) {
    let coordinates = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('coordinates');
    coordinates = coordinates.split(",");
    coordinates = coordinates.map(coordinate => parseInt(coordinate));
    const [row, col] = coordinates;

    let grid = this.state.grid;
    let cell = grid[row][col];

    let { isPointerDown, pointerStatus } = this.state;
    if (updatePointerDown) {
        isPointerDown = true;
      pointerStatus = !cell;
    }

        grid[row][col] = pointerStatus;

    this.setState({
        grid: grid,
      isPointerDown: isPointerDown,
      pointerStatus: pointerStatus
    });
  }

  handlePointerDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.updateCell(e, true);
  }

  handlePointerOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.isPointerDown) {
        this.updateCell(e);
    }
  }

  handlePointerUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({isPointerDown: false});
  }

  evolve(e) {
    if (e) { e.preventDefault(); }
    let currentGen = this.state.grid;
    let nextGen = [];

    currentGen.forEach((row, rowIdx) => {
        nextGen.push([]);
        row.forEach((cell, colIdx) => {
        const numNeighbors = this.countNeighbors(rowIdx, colIdx);
        if (currentGen[rowIdx][colIdx]) {
            if (numNeighbors >= 2 && numNeighbors <= 3) {
            nextGen[rowIdx].push(true);
          } else {
            nextGen[rowIdx].push(false);
          }
        } else {
            if (numNeighbors == 3) {
            nextGen[rowIdx].push(true);
          } else {
            nextGen[rowIdx].push(false);
          }
        }
      });
    });

    this.setState({grid: nextGen});
  }

  countNeighbors(rowIdx, colIdx) {
    const { grid } = this.state;
    let numNeighbors = 0;
    for (let dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
        if (grid[rowIdx + dy] ) {
        for (let dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
          if (grid[rowIdx + dy][colIdx + dx] && (dy != 0 || dx != 0)) {
            numNeighbors++;
          }
            }
      }
    }
    return numNeighbors;
  }

  clearGrid(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const grid = this.createNewGrid();
    this.setState({grid: grid});
  }

  toggleStart(e) {
    let { isStarted, ticksPerSecond, intervalId } = this.state;

    if (!isStarted) {
        intervalId = setInterval(this.evolve, 1000 / ticksPerSecond);
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }

    this.setState({ 
        isStarted: !isStarted,
      intervalId: intervalId
    });
  }

  updateTicksPerSecond(e) {
    this.setState({ticksPerSecond: e.currentTarget.value});
  }

  render() {
    const { grid, ticksPerSecond, isStarted } = this.state;

    return (
        <div>
        <div id="grid" onPointerUp={this.handlePointerUp}>
          {
            grid.map((row, rowIdx) => (
              <div className="row" key={rowIdx.toString()}>
                {row.map((cell, colIdx) => (
                  <div className={"cell " + (cell ? "alive": "dead")} onPointerDown={this.handlePointerDown} onPointerOver={this.handlePointerOver} coordinates={[rowIdx, colIdx]} key={[rowIdx, colIdx]} />
                ))}
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.clearGrid}>Clear</button>
        <button onClick={this.evolve}>Next</button>
        <button onClick={this.toggleStart}>{ isStarted ? "Pause" : "Start" }</button>
        <input
          type="text" 
          value={ticksPerSecond}
          onChange={this.updateTicksPerSecond}  
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<GameOfLife />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about [what your code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226) and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The current title states your concerns about the code; it needs an [edit] to simply *state the task*; see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.